# unzip operation taking several hours

Tags: python, unzip

I am using the following shell script to loop over 90 zip files & unarchive them on a Linux box hosted with Hostinger (Shared web hosting)

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="<path_to_archives>"

cd ${SOURCE_DIR}

for f in *.zip
do
#   unzip -oqq "$f" -d "${f%.zip}" &
    python3 scripts/extract_archives.py "${f}" &
done
wait
```

The python script being called by the above shell script is below -

```
import shutil
import sys

source_path = "<path to source dir>"

def extract_files(in_file):
    shutil.unpack_archive(source_path + in_file, source_path + in_file.split('.')[0])
    print('Extracted : ', in_file)


extract_files(sys.argv[1].strip())
```

Irrespective of whether I use the inbuilt `unzip` command or a python, it's taking about 2.5 hours to unzip all the files. unarchiving all the zip files results 90 folders with 170000 files overall. I would've thought anywhere between 15/20 min is reasonably acceptable timeframe.

I've tried a few different variations in that, I have tried just tarring the folders instead of zipping them up thinking just un-tarring may be faster than unzipping. I've used tar command  from source server to transfer the files over ssh & untar in memory something like this -

```
time tar zcf - . | ssh -p <port> user@host "tar xzf - -C <dest dir>"
```

Nothing is helping. I am open to using any other programming language like Perl, Go or others too if necessary to speed things up.

Please can someone help me solve this performance problem.

Comment: If `unzip` gets the same time, then It should be clear that the programming language is not the bottleneck here.  170,000 files is a hell of a lot.  How large are these files?  How many bytes total?  In a shared hosting setup, your CPU time is often throttled for fairness.  How did you decide 20 minutes is fair?  Have you tried this on your own computer?

Comment: The bottleneck for something like this is almost always the disk, not the unpacking code.

Comment: Are the files (reasonably) evenly distributed over the folders?  Having too many files in a single directory can slow the system down a lot. While 2k files in a folder is fine if one folder happens to have 100k files then that could be a problem.  (And, it's just a lot of files anyway.)

Comment: could you use https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop to parallelize in bash ... or parallelize in python  ... but the other comment are very good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers. As you indicated, this was to do with throttling on the servers in a hosted environment